# After update theme options how to update Woocommerce Cart Session?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I have a custom theme options page ( In WordPress Site ) and in that option I have a couple of options for WooCoommerce Mini Cart Customization.

Everything works fine as expected but every time I update some option from backend I can't see that changes right way in frontend due to WooCommerce Cart Session.

As you know WooCommerce mini cart Or custom cart won't be updated automatically if that cart is going through `add_to_cart_fragments`, So, every time after changing the options I need to update cart session by doing add to cart, remove cart item or update cart item etc.

Honestly, I'm little clueless here, All I want to do is after an update my theme options from backend I want to clear WooCommerce cart session/cache, So, I can see the changes right way without updating or adding anything.

I know WooCommerce cart session can be updated through an ajax But if I going to update theme options in the backend I how can run an ajax in the frontend that will clear WooCommerce cart session for me?

Or have anyone have an idea about it. let me know if you guys don't get me what really I want to do.

Hope it makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: It actually depends upon your code actually. Long before i customized the cart session, such problem was not found for me. 
Do you want to empty the cart or need your setting to be reflected in frontend?

Comment: need your setting to be reflected in frontend. As you know it's not reflected right way unless WooCommerce cart action has been done.

Comment: Yes, but there might be session hooks where your setting might be update without any issue. I will also look on such hooks if i find.